# Querytables error 1004 when importing text files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that retrieves text files from a directory which works fine.
The code is correct since it imports all files and adds a graph.
But, sometimes unexpectedly the query is unable to find the files and gives an excecution error 1004 saying the file is either unexistant or used in another program. It stops working for a while than starts working again.

Since the original directory is on a local server, i originally though the file was actually being used by someone else but the error persists even after copying the file on a local path.

Here are the constants that constitute the directory :

```
Public Const symosDir As String = "C:\\Users\cdenis\Desktop\Mettre sur réseau\Bibliothèque amortisseurs WinSymos(08-02-23)\"
Public Const d_symosDir As String = symosDir & "fdyn\"
Public Const a_symosDir As String = symosDir & "fam\"
Public Const s_symosDir As String = symosDir & "fstat\"
```

here is how qPath (the querytable's path) is constructed :

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 4 'loop axe d, fdyn
    axe = "d" & i
    qPath = "TEXT;" & d_symosDir & nom & axe & ".bl"
    query ws, rng, nom, axe, qPath, cht
Next i
```

And Here's an example of the complete qPath :

```
TEXT;C:\\Users\cdenis\Desktop\Mettre sur réseau\Bibliothèque amortisseurs WinSymos(08-02-23)\fdyn\CB1700-20d1.bl
```

Here's the sub where the query is created :

```
Sub query(ws, rng, nom, axe, qPath, cht)
Dim qt

rng.Value = nom 'Ecrire le nom de l'amo dans entete
rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = axe 'Ecrire le nom de l'axe à une colonne du nom

'On Error Resume Next

'Ouvrir le fichier text au chemin qPath et coller une ligne en dessous du nom de l'axe
Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=qPath, Destination:=rng.Offset(1, 0))

With qt
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False 'Desactiver l'actualisation
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells 'Supprimer les cellules
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False 'Garder les colonnes taille de base
    .TextFileStartRow = 3 'Copier à partir de la 3eme lignes
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False 'Desactiver les messages
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited 'Collage des donner en formattant les collonnes en cellule en fonction d'un délimiteur
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierNone 'Dit text sous format text sans ""
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True 'Délimiteur choisi ","
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1) 'Copier les données dans un tableau de 1 col 1 ligne
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True 'Considerer les "-" devant les nb comme des nb neg
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 'Desactiver l'actualisation
End With

qt.Delete 'Supprimer la requête

If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'Si erreur chemin ou nom invalide
    Err.Clear
    MsgBox "La nom " & nom & ", l'axe " & axe & " ou le chemin suivant sont invalides." & vbNewLine & _
           qPath
    Exit Sub 'Sortir
End If
On Error GoTo 0 'Retirer les erreurs

CreerGraph ws, cht, axe, rng 'Créer un graph / Ajouter une série

Set rng = rng.End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2) 'Sauter deux colonnes
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if that's the (only) issue, but it's `C:\Users` (only one backslash)

Comment: I saw people putting 2 backslashs on querytable directory so i did the same not knowing what it'll do. The query directory displayed in the error ignores this and shows only one backslash. I tried both, it doesn't seem to change anything.